Is $f$ Borel measurable to a metric space if and only if it is the limit of simple measurable functions?
Let $\def\AAA{\mathcal{A}} \def\BBB{\mathcal{B}}$
$f:(X,\AAA)\to (Y,\BBB_Y)$ be a function from a measurable space $(X,\AAA)$ to a Borel space $(Y,\BBB_Y)$, meaning $\BBB_Y$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by a fixed metrizable topology on $Y$. I've been wondering if the following result is true:
Theorem (?): $f$ is measurable if and only if it is the limit of simple measurable functions.

The result is true if the word 'simple' is removed, as shown here.

Is there anything you tried?

If $\langle f_n\rangle$ is a sequence of simple functions converging to $f$, then the values of must lie in the closure of the union of the ranges of the $f_n$. In particular, $f$ must have a separable range.
So, a simple counterexample is the identity function on a nonseparable metric space (i.e., an uncountable discrete metric space).
